# Mutiple Mutators in Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

To define a Mutator in a Eloquent Model class, we use the getFooAttribute like:

```
public function getTitleAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

But imagine that i have a lot (20 to 30) attributes in one Model that i'd like to rename, it's fastidious to create a function for each one, is there any smarter way to resolve this?

Comment: if you have 20-30 attributes you'd like to rename then maybe you need to take a step back and review your table structure, data types and how you're using the database.

Comment: I m working on a production DB, it isn't my design; i solved my problem by using resources

Comment: Do share your solution as an answer. It sound like something that might help others.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the [`getAttribute`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L306) function on your model and have an associative array in there to rename the attributes.

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $renames = [
        'foo' => 'bar',
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $renames))
        $key = $renames[$key];

    return parent::getAttribute($key);
}
```